# zsh jump to the end of copy from X clipboard

Tags: zsh, clipboard

I would like to get Ctrl + V and Ctrl + X to paste / copy from zsh to X11. I found the following snippet to work but zsh does not jump to the character after paste. How could I do that.

```
copy-to-clipboard ()
{ 
  if [ -n "$LBUFFER$RBUFFER" ]; then
    echo $LBUFFER$RBUFFER | xclip -i
  fi
}

paste-from-clipboard ()
{
  CLIPOUT=`xclip -o`
  BUFFER=$LBUFFER$CLIPOUT$RBUFFER
} 


zle -N paste-from-clipboard paste-from-clipboard
zle -N copy-to-clipboard copy-to-clipboard
bindkey "^V" paste-from-clipboard
bindkey "^X" copy-to-clipboard
```

Comment: In `copy-to-clipboard`, you're adding an extra newline, and it won't work in a few edge cases. Make it `print -nr -- $BUFFER | xclip -i`

Answer (score 1):

zsh keeps the position of the cursor in the variable `CURSOR` so:

```
paste-from-clipboard ()
{
  CLIPOUT=`xclip -o`
  BUFFER=$LBUFFER$CLIPOUT$RBUFFER
  CURSOR=$(( $CURSOR + ${#CLIPOUT} ))
}
```

Comment: or simply `LBUFFER+=$(xclip -o)`

Comment: @Gilles is right , small note, don't add spaces to it.